# Curl CLI - Saving Cookies PLUS login

Tags: curl, command-line-interface

The Manual at http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html is a bit "quick" and I didn't get how to do do this.

I need to save all cokies (and sessions cookies) and then login to a site via CLI.

Till here, it seams it works (saving and reading):

`curl -b cookies -c cookies http://www.theknot.com`

Tried to use NETRC (a file ".netrc" with user and password in the format: machine curl.haxx.se login iamdaniel password mysecret):

`curl -n -L -b cookies -c cookies http://global.theknot.com/join/memberlogin.aspx`

But it does not do the magic:

`curl -L -n -b cookies -c cookies http://www.theknot.com/wedding-dress/mon-cheri-bridals/211249?src=par`

For it keeps redirecting to the login page...

Does anybody has already been throught this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the type of login you want. What you need to send post data directly to whatever script handles login. To send post data specifically:

> 4.2 POST
>       The GET method makes all input field names get displayed in the URL
>   field of   your browser. That's
>   generally a good thing when you want
>   to be able to   bookmark that page
>   with your given data, but it is an
>   obvious disadvantage   if you entered
>   secret information in one of the
>   fields or if there are a   large
>   amount of fields creating a very long
>   and unreadable URL.
>       The HTTP protocol then offers the POST method. This way the client sends
>   the   data separated from the URL and
>   thus you won't see any of it in the
>   URL   address field.
>       The form would look very similar to the previous one:
>
> ```
>     <form method="POST" action="junk.cgi">
>       <input type=text name="birthyear">
>       <input type=submit name=press value=" OK ">
>     </form>
> And to use curl to post this form with the same data filled in as
> ```
>
> before, we   could do it like:
>
> ```
>     curl --data "birthyear=1905&press=%20OK%20"
> ```
>
> http://www.example.com/when.cgi
>       This kind of POST will use the Content-Type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded and
>   is the most widely used POST kind.
>       The data you send to the server MUST already be properly encoded, curl
>   will   not do that for you. For
>   example, if you want the data to
>   contain a space,   you need to replace
>   that space with %20 etc. Failing to
>   comply with this   will most likely
>   cause your data to be received wrongly
>   and messed up.
>       Recent curl versions can in fact url-encode POST data for you, like
>   this:
>
> ```
>     curl --data-urlencode "name=I am Daniel" http://www.example.com
> ```

Source: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html

Comment: Thank youm but it did not work. It looks that the javascript validator stops curl to post...